# How can I add apple pay in shopify store using authorize.net?

Tags: shopify, authorize.net, applepay

Is there any custom way to integrate apple pay using authorize.net in a shopify store.
Or
Is the link below the only way?
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/payments/third-party-providers/set-up-authorize-net